# Changes made to airflow.cfg file not reflecting when running airflow as a service

Tags: centos-7, systemd

I'm running airflow 1.10.11 as systemd service on Centos 7 server.

I want to change logging location to a different folder. For that I changed `base_log_folder = /code/python/airflow/airflow/logs` from `base_log_folder = /home/cel/sm/airflow/logs`(Airflow_Home) in `airflow.cfg` file.

After doing this when I'm restarting scheduler and webserver using `sudo systemctl restart airflow-scheduler` and `sudo systemctl restart airflow-webserver`; logging is still happening in old log folder i.e `/home/cel/sm/airflow/logs`.

I referred this link to change log folder location: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/write-logs.html

Don't know what I'm missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: By changing `base_log_folder` value you only changed the logs directory for tasks, you also need to change logs directory for scheduler by changing `child_process_log_directory` value in `airflow.cfg`**

There are actually two types of logging in airflow:

- Task logging, writting the logs of tasks in a DAG
- Processor logging, writting the airflow scheduler logs

Logs directory those two kind of logging are set in two different configuration in file `airflow.cfg` as of airflow 2.0:

- `base_log_folder` in section `[logging]` for Task logging, with default value `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs`
- `child_process_log_directory` in section `[scheduler]` for Processor logging with default value `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs/scheduler`

Restarting airflow-scheduler and airflow-webserver processes with systemd reloads configuration. So I guess logs still written in your old logs directory are only the  scheduler's logs and you should be able to correct it by changing `child_process_log_directory` value as follow:

```
child_process_log_directory = /code/python/airflow/airflow/logs/scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the workers as well (in case you're using celery or something like that). For me, I just restarted the the EC2 and the logs redirection worked. Try restarting the server if it's possible.